# Blank screen at the beginning of the installation

Tags: installation, drivers, graphics, screen

I have been trying for some time now to get Ubuntu working on my computer with proprietary NVIDIA drivers, having tried and failed many times decided to take a go at Xubuntu.

However I think I might have been messing around too much and now every time I try to reinstall Ubuntu or Xubuntu using a Live pen, as soon as I press enter on "Install Ubuntu" (or Xubuntu) the screen goes black and does nothing, but the computer remains on.

Is there a way to solve this without totally formatting everything?

I have Intel Integrated Graphics + NVIDIA 650M. Windows 8 installed in one hard drive and had Ubuntu installed in a partition of a separate harddrive. I thought this might be leftovers from the Ubuntu Config so I tried to delete the partition and `fixmbr` and `fixboot` from windows command prompt. I know this is a mess of totally noob mistakes but I still want to try and get it fixed.

Comment: Also look at - [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/a/156120) once you have installed ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to Win 8, reinstall ihr ISO to your pen drive again with PENDRIVELINUX(google it), boot again with your pendrive

OR

Get to Ubuntu with the pen as a live USB and try installing ubuntu from there dude.

Comment: That is what I tried to do, I used Pendrive linux, and I get that menu "Try Ubuntu without installing" , "Install Ubuntu", etc... after I press "Install Ubuntu" the screen goes black and the computer doesn't do anything.